# Laravel + slick.js: using a form to save image id's to database

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Laravel 5.1 and slick.js. Currently I am displaying a column of 3 images (top, middle, bottom). In generating the column I added the image id's to the `<img>` tags.

My goal is for the user to be able to save a set of images, one each from top/middle/bottom by hitting a "save" button but I am unsure how to identify the images since in slick.js all of the image src's are in the html page despite it showing one at a time.

I messed around with using slickCurrentSlide but got stuck since it returns the index of available images rather than the image id.

```
<div class="single-item-tops" style="text-align: center;">
   @foreach($tops as $top)
      <div><img src="{{$top->src}}" id="{{$top->id}}" class="img-thumbnail" /></div>
   @endforeach
</div><br>

<div class="single-item-bottoms">
  @foreach($bottoms as $bottom)
   <div><img src="{{$bottom->src}}" id="{{$bottom->id}}" class="img-thumbnail"/></div>
  @endforeach
</div><br>

<div class="single-item-shoes">
    @foreach($shoes as $shoe)
     <div><img src="{{$shoe->src}}" id="{{$shoe->id}}" class="img-thumbnail" /></div>
    @endforeach
</div>

<form method="POST" action="/outfits/create" class="myForm">
   <input type="hidden" name="top" class="top" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="bottom" value="">
   input type="hidden" name="shoe" value="">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary disabled btn-block">Save Outfit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.single-item-tops').slick({
         arrows: false,
         adaptiveHeight: true
     });

    //     $('.single-item-tops').on('afterChange', function(event, slick,  currentSlide){
    //   confirm(currentSlide);
    // });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.single-item-bottoms').slick({
        arrows: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.single-item-shoes').slick({
        arrows: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true
        });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: It would be better if you include your codes here

Comment: Added. Sorry about that.

Comment: Solved: add data-id to the <div> tags with contain the images was the answer.